# Managed bean instance variable gives exceptions when JSF file is executed

Tags: jsf, el

I am new in JSF and my first JSF 2.2 application is giving me some errors that I don't understand. This is how the application works:

A user will type a text in the **form.xhtml** file and the text he entered will be displayed in the **result.xhtml** file.

When **form.xhtml** displays when the application lunches I want to display a message at the top of the form. The message comes from  a default value in an instance variable that is in the managed bean.

It is displaying the text from the instance variable that is given me problems now. I don't understand why displaying a default text from instance variable gives me problems.

I'm using Eclipse and Glassfish now

This is the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Navigator {
 
    private String name;
    private String defaultMsg = "THIS IS MY DEFAULT MESSAGE";
 
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getDefaultMsg() {
        return defaultMsg;
    }
    public void setDefaultMsg(String defaultMsg) {
        this.defaultMsg = defaultMsg;
    }
}
```

I have two xhtml files:

```
// form.xhtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
 
<h:body>
        <h:outputText value="#{navigator.defaultMsg}" />
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{navigator.name}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Say Hello" action="result" />
    </h:form>
    
</h:body>
 
</html>


// result.xhtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
 
<h:body>
    <h3>Hello #{navigator.name} !</h3>
</h:body>
 
</html>
```

This is the problem I don't understand: when I run my code without `<h:outputText value="#{navigator.defaultMsg}" />` in
**form.xhtml**, everything works fine. But if include that portion in the file, I get this error in the browser:

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: /form.xhtml @8,51 value="#{navigator.defaultMsg}": The class 'jsf.Navigator' does not have the property 'defaultMsg'.
root cause

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /form.xhtml @8,51 value="#{navigator.defaultMsg}": The class 'jsf.Navigator' does not have the property 'defaultMsg'.
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1.2.2 logs.
```

**The class 'jsf.Navigator' does not have the property 'defaultMsg'.**

**jsf** is the name of the project and **Navigator** is the class name

What I don't understand is how come the instance variable **defaultMsg** is in the class but it can't recognized it. Does it have to do with the way managed beans are initialized?

Comment: Can try placing the h:outputText inside the h:form tag ?